# What is the story behind a Getter?

Tags: haskell, haskell-lens

I stumbled upon [Getter](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/lens-4.14/docs/src/Control.Lens.Type.html#Getter) definition having both `Functor` and `Contravariant` constraint on `f`.

It's not surprising that "getter" can't do much with the "contained part" but this signature looks like a [Phantom](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/contravariant-1.4/docs/src/Data.Functor.Contravariant.html#phantom) in a "van Laarhoven" setting of `(a -> f a) -> s -> f s`. Is the implicit constraint "`s` knows about `a`" represented this way in `lens`?

How can I find source code of some concrete instances of a `Getter` so that I can see `map` and `contramap` being used?

Answer (score 8):

The idea of a `Getter` is that it is a read-only lens. Given a `Getter s a` you can pull an `a` out of an `s`, but you can't put one in. The type is defined thus:

```
type Getter s a = forall f. (Contravariant f, Functor f) => (a -> f a) -> s -> f s
```

When a type is both a `Functor` and `Contravariant`, it actually doesn't depend on its type argument at all:

```
import Data.Void

change :: (Functor f, Contravariant f) => f a -> f b
change = fmap absurd . contramap absurd
```

Such a functor will always look very much like `Const b` for some `b`.

So a `Getter s a` is essentially

```
type Getter s a = forall b . (a -> b) -> s -> b
```

but to make it work with the rest of the lens ecosystem it has extra polymorphism.

Comment: Or the other way: `change = contramap (const ()) . fmap (const ())`

Comment: @Gurkenglas, yes, either terminal object will do. I didn't notice that.

Answer (score 5):

Well, a getter is basically just a function. The isomorphism is this:

```
getter :: (Functor f, Contravariant f) => (s->a) -> (a->f a) -> s->f s
getter f q = contramap f . q . f
```

Here, the `contramap` will in effect do nothing but coerce the types, because as you say, combining `Functor` and `Contravariant` amounts to requiring that `f x` doesn't actually contain an `x`. Basically, ensuring this is also the only reason the `Functor` constraint is there.

Comment: What would you get if you didn't have the Functor constraint? It'd still be producable from an (s -> a), and turnable into an (s -> a), right?

Comment: Well, to go back to a plain function you just need to instantiate `f` suitably, usually done with `Const`, which of course happens to have a `Functor` instance too.

Comment: Yea but you could also use other `Contravariant`s that happen not to have a Functor instance, right? Or do you mean that wouldn't give us more power, because you can turn a Getter into a function, and use that function to construct the thing that we wanted to do that couldnt provide a Functor constraint?

Comment: Follow the types they said! I just revisited this and there is a story right there in the module documentation! I'd love to accept this answer, may I ask for some hint for understanding CPS tranfromation for completeness?   https://hackage.haskell.org/package/lens-4.16.1/docs/Control-Lens-Getter.html

Answer (score 1):

The type

```
Getter s a = forall f . (Contravariant f, Functor f) => (a -> f a) -> (s -> f s)
```

is isomorphic to the type `s -> a`. The two sides of the isomorphism are given by

```
toGetter :: (s -> a) -> Getter s a
toGetter h alpha = contramap h . alpha . h
fromGetter :: Getter s a -> (s -> a)
fromGetter getter = getConst . getter Const
```

It is not hard to see that `fromGetter (toGetter h)` equals `h`.

Up to this point (i.e. in order to implement `toGetter` and `fromGetter` and to prove that `fromGetter . toGetter = id`) we have not used the `Functor f` constraint. This constraint is however necessary in order to prove that `toGetter . fromGetter = id`.

---

First assume that `f` is both a covariant `Functor` and a `Contravariant` functor. Then any function `g :: x -> y` yields functions `fmap g :: f x -> f y` and `contramap g :: f y -> f x`. Parametricity, combined with the functor laws, entails that these are mutually inverse, i.e. `f x ≅ f y`. Hence, `f` is (up to isomorphism) a constant functor, so we can think of `Getter s a` as being defined as

```
Getter s a = forall f0 . (a -> b) -> (s -> b)
```

(as mentioned in dfeuer's answer). By the Yoneda lemma, this is isomorphic to `s -> a`.

---

Remarkably, if we lift the `Functor f` constraint:

```
OddGetter s a = forall f . Contravariant f => (a -> f a) -> (s -> f s)
```

then we obtain a subtype of `Getter s a` that is no longer isomorphic to `s -> a`, but instead to `s -> Aux a s`:

```
newtype Aux a x = Aux {aAux :: a, gAux :: x -> a}
instance Contravariant (Aux a) where
  contramap f (Aux a g) = Aux a (g . f)

toAux :: a -> Aux a a
toAux a = Aux a id
```

*`(Aux a, toAux)` is the initial of all pairs `(F, toF)` where `F` is a contravariant functor and `toF :: a -> F a`, similar to how `(Const a, Const)` is the initial of all pairs `(F, toF)` where `F` is a co- and contravariant functor and `toF :: a -> F a`.*

The two sides of the isomorphism can be implemented as follows:

```
toOddGetter :: (s -> Aux a s) -> OddGetter s a
toOddGetter sigma alpha s1 =
    contramap (\s2 -> gAux (sigma s1) s2) $ alpha $ aAux (sigma s1)
fromOddGetter :: OddGetter s a -> (s -> Aux a s)
fromOddGetter getter = getter toAux
```

Again, it is straightforward to check that `fromOddGetter . toOddGetter = id`, which already shows that `OddGetter s a` is **not** isomorphic to `s -> a`. To prove that `fromOddGetter . toOddGetter = id`, we again need a parametricity argument.

Parametricity entails that, for any natural transformation `nu :: forall x . d x -> f x`, any `getter :: OddGetter s a` and any `alphaD :: a -> d a`, we have

```
nu . getter alphaD = getter (nu . alphaD) :: s -> f s
```

Now, we instantiate `d` with `Aux a`, `alphaD` with `toAux` and `nu` with `factor alpha` (for an arbitrary `alpha : a -> f a`):

```
factor :: (a -> f a) -> forall x . Aux a x -> f x
factor alpha (Aux a g) = contramap g $ alpha a
```

which has the property that `factor alpha . toAux = alpha`. Then we have

```
factor alpha . getter toAux = getter (factor alpha . toAux) = getter alpha :: s -> f s
```

Now when we apply this to some `s1 :: s`, we find that `getter alpha s1` (the applied RHS) equals

```
factor alpha (getter toAux s1)
  = contramap (gAux $ getter toAux s1) $ alpha (aAux $ getter toAux s1)
    {-by definition of factor-}
  = contramap (\s2 -> gAux (getter toAux s1) s2) $ alpha $ aAux (getter toAux s1)
    {-by eta-expansion and regrouping-}
  = toOddGetter (getter toAux) alpha s1
    {-by definition of toOddGetter-}
  = toOddGetter (fromOddGetter getter) alpha s1
    {-by definition of fromOddGetter-}
```

i.e. `getter = toOddGetter (fromOddGetter getter)`.

---

Given the isomorphisms, it is perhaps remarkable that the type

```
OddGetter s a ≅ s -> Aux a s
```

is a subtype of

```
Getter s a ≅ s -> a
```

The "coercion" function

```
\ getter -> getter :: OddGetter s a -> Getter s a
```

corresponds to the function

```
\ sigma -> aAux . sigma :: (s -> Aux a s) -> (s -> a)
```

under these isomorphisms.

Comment: Possibly best answer out there but I suspect few people could tell whether it's right or wrong!